# How to add custom css to a Sharepoint App (iframe)

Tags: css, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-apps

I add the contact us form app from the store and I have a custom template in my site collection but the app see so bad, so I need to shande the colors of the app. How can I do that?

This is how it looks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1) add reference to your custom css to the page (you can use SP Designer for that) where the form is located ..

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="cssFileName" Name="FolderName/FileName.css" runat="server" />
```

css file should be located here: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033\STYLES\ (or relevant folder for 2013.)

2) or add content editor webpart (editing page in web view) and add reference to your custom css file there..